# How can I detect the last picture and disable the next button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to develop  a popup which contains pictures in it but now the problem is when I click on the next button and the pictures finish , then I see the alt text 
which I dont want to see I whant the code to detect  the last picture and disables the next button. and also on the prev buttton I want it to be like that .
I have tried in the codes below but no luck :

```
//Here is the html part 
<div id="popup_boxAvian1"> 
<div class="divsAvian">
<div class ="mainimage1"><img src="images/avian/pdf1.jpg" alt="alt" /></div>
<div class ="mainimage2"><img src="images/avian/pdf2.jpg" alt="alt" /></div>
<div class ="mainimage3"><img src="images/avian/pdf3.jpg" alt="alt" /></div>
<div class ="mainimage4"><img src="images/avian/pdf4.jpg" alt="alt" /></div>
<div class ="mainimage5"><img src="images/avaian/pdf5.jpg" alt="alt" /></div>
</div>
<a id="prevAvian1">prev</a>
<a id="nextAvian1">next</a>
 <a id="popupBoxCloseAvian1">Close</a>   
</div>
</div>


//This is Jquery codes

$(document).ready(function(){


/*I am trying to disable the next button on the last picture */
if($(".divsAvian div:last")){
$("#nextAvian1").hide();
}
/*I am trying to dis able the next button on the last picture ends */

    $(".divsAvian div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#nextAvian1").click(function(){
        if ($(".divsAvian div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divsAvian div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();

        else {
            $(".divsAvian div:visible").hide();
            $(".divsAvian div:first").show();
        }

        return false;
    });

    $("#prevAvian1").click(function(){
        if ($(".divsAvian div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divsAvian div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divsAvian div:visible").hide();
            $(".divsAvian div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `.each` block is unnecessary - `$('.divsAvian div').hide().first().show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to check if the target element is visible:

```
/*I am trying to disable the next button on the last picture */
if($(".divsAvian div:last").is(':visible')){
    $("#nextAvian1").hide();
}else if($(".divsAvian div:first").is(':visible')){
    $("#prevAvian1").hide();
}
```

[**{See the demo here}**](http://jsfiddle.net/FgTrm/)

Comment: Still visible but your effort is appreciated

Comment: Yes I saw it but the prev is un clickable

Comment: yes that is because i have not bind any event to the buttons. That is a demonstration of show and hide of buttons when specific div is visible.

Comment: Okay but the answer you gave here I applied it they it is but I still get no results and to me it looks okay and I really don't know why it does not work